# error while import functional component + Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I am facing the below issue in my test (enzyme test file) . I wanted to create test file for the below component. When i import  it to my test file , throwed an error.

**Error**

```
    Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or 
a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, 
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

    Check the render method of `FormElement`.

      10 |     }
      11 |     it("render the formelement",()=>{
    > 12 |         mount(<FormElement {...props}/>)
         |         ^
      13 |     })
      14 | })
```

My FormElement component

```
import React from "react";
import '../Styles/Form.scss';

function FormElement({ component: headerComponent,  headerName }) {
    return (
        <section className="form_section">
            <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <h3 style={{ paddingLeft: "15px" }}>{headerName}</h3>
            </div>
            {headerComponent}
        </section>
    );
}

export default FormElement;
```

My test file **FormElement.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {mount} from "enzyme";
import  FormElement from "./FormElement";

describe("FormElement component",()=> {
    const props = {
        headerName: "test",
        component : null
    }
    it("render the formelement",()=>{
        mount(<FormElement {...props}/>)
    })
})
```

My project directory would be like
`ui/src/Components/Forms/Common/FormElement.js`
`ui/src/Components/Forms/Common/FormElement.test.js`

I tried couple of ways like change FormElement component in to const like

```
const FormElement = () =>{
.....,
}
export default FormElement;
```

then in **test file**
import FormElement from "./FormElement"

But nothing is working i am not sure what is missing my end , could anyone please suggest .